# icCube mapping a dimension attribute to a measure group

Tags: iccube

I'm trying to figure out the best way to link a dimension to a fact table and having some trouble finding an example in the documentation. All of my data sources are csv files and I have the following 2 data tables:

Areas table with columns: Area,DateTime,Cost  (Area,DateTime are unique)
Company table with columns: CompanyID,Area (CompanyID is unique and represents a dimension)

I would like to link the Company Dimension to the Cost measure from the Areas table. However, it seems that I can only link the Company dimension to the Areas measure group through the dimension key, which is CompanyID. Is there a way around this or do I need to add a CompanyID column to my Areas csv file prior to loading.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve but it looks as you could use a many-to-many cube to create a link from Area to Company (even though it might be a one-to-on relation).

1) Create a many-to-many cube using your Company table (Advanced/Many-to-Many)

2) Bind the Company dimension in the facts, Area table, using the defined many-to-many relation.

Some documentation [here](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_many2many.php) (the first image is wrong).

hope it helps.